# How to merge two list columns when merging DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two `DataFrame`:

**df1:**

```
       date        ids
0   2015-10-13       [978]
1   2015-10-14  [978, 121]
```

**df2:**

```
       date        ids
0   2015-10-13  [978, 12]
1   2015-10-14     [2, 1]
```

When I merge them based on `date` as below:

```
df = pandas.merge(df1, df2, on='date', sort=False)
```

I will have the below `DataFrame`:

```
   date            ids_x             ids_y
0   2015-10-13    [978]            [978, 12]
1   2015-10-14    [978, 121]       [2, 1]
```

I want to have **one** `ids` column merged from both lists like `[978, 978, 12]` or preferably removing duplicates and have something like `[978, 12]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add both columns together to get the list you are looking for, and then use `df.drop()` with `axis=1` to drop the `ids_x` and `ids_y` columns. Example -

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date', sort=False)
df['ids'] = df['ids_x'] + df['ids_y']
df = df.drop(['ids_x','ids_y'],axis=1)
```

Demo -

```
In [65]: df
Out[65]:
         date       ids_x      ids_y
0  2015-10-13       [978]  [978, 12]
1  2015-10-14  [978, 121]     [2, 1]

In [67]: df['ids'] = df['ids_x'] + df['ids_y']

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
         date       ids_x      ids_y               ids
0  2015-10-13       [978]  [978, 12]    [978, 978, 12]
1  2015-10-14  [978, 121]     [2, 1]  [978, 121, 2, 1]

In [70]: df = df.drop(['ids_x','ids_y'],axis=1)

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
         date               ids
0  2015-10-13    [978, 978, 12]
1  2015-10-14  [978, 121, 2, 1]
```

---

If you want to remove the duplicate values as well, and you *do not care about order*, then you can use `Series.apply` and then convert the list to `set` and then back to `list`. Example -

```
df['ids'] = df['ids'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

Demo -

```
In [72]: df['ids'] = df['ids'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

In [73]: df
Out[73]:
         date               ids
0  2015-10-13         [978, 12]
1  2015-10-14  [121, 978, 2, 1]
```

---

Or as asked in comments if you want to do it with `numpy.unique()` , you can use that along with `Series.apply` as well -

```
import numpy as np
df['ids'] = df['ids'].apply(lambda x: np.unique(x))
```

Demo -

```
In [79]: df['ids'] = df['ids'].apply(lambda x: np.unique(x))

In [80]: df
Out[80]:
         date               ids
0  2015-10-13         [12, 978]
1  2015-10-14  [1, 2, 121, 978]
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to drop duplicates with `numpy.unique()` as it is much more efficient than `set()`?

Comment: Yes, its possible, added that as well to the answer.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for the time. +1

Comment: @AlirezaHos Please note, according to my test, `set` is a bit faster than `numpy.unique` .

Comment: You are right! `Numpy.unique` took `0.16` second while `set` took `0.05` second for 30,000 ids. It is fast.

Comment: If we want to do the same concatenation on more than two columns ids columns and still keeping the order without removing any duplicates, how can we proceed without explicitly write the concat for each column?

Comment: How to also avoid null values if present in a list? I don't want to see empty values merged with a comma.

Comment: this approach (+) throws an error for me if one of the list columns is ever an empty list

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
df = pandas.merge(df1, df2, on='date', sort=False)
df['ids'] = df['ids_x'] + df['ids_y']
df = df.drop(['ids_x','ids_y'], 1)
```

For merging two lists use `apply` function:

```
df['ids'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(set(row['ids'])), axis=1)
```