# Append List to a Spark Data frame column based on matching Keys from a second data frame

Tags: apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, pyspark

I have 2 spark data frames with same column names and want to expand some columns in the first df using the list in the same column in the df2 when the key columns matched with each other.

```
df1:
+----+---+--++------+---------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
|k1  |  k2  |list1  | list2   |list3|list4   |list5   |list 6 |
+----+---+--+-------+---------------------------------+-------+
|   a| 121  |[car1] |[price1] |[1]  |[False] |[0.000] |[vfdvf]|
|   b| 11   |[car3] |[price3] |[2]  |[False] |[1.000] |[00000]|
|   c| 23   |[car3] |[price3] |[4]  |[False] |[2.500] |[fdabh]|
|   d| 250  |[car6] |[price6] |[6]  |[True]  |[0.450] |[00000]|
+----+---+--++----+---+--+--++----+---+------+----------------+


df2:
+----+---+--++------+---------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
|k1  |  k2  |list1  | list2   |list3|list4   |list5   |list 6 |
+----+---+--+-------+---------------------------------+-------+
|   m| 121  |[car5] |[price5] |[5]  |[False] |[3.000] |[vfdvf]|
|   b| 11   |[car8] |[price8] |[8]  |[False] |[2.000] |[mnfaf]|
|   c| 23   |[car7] |[price7] |[7]  |[False] |[1.500] |[00000]|
|   n| 250  |[car9] |[price9] |[9]  |[False] |[0.450] |[00000]|
+----+---+--++----+---+--+--++----+---+------+----------------+
```

since the columns with list of items are related to each other the orders have to stay the same. Is there a way I can append the whole list from df2 to df1 only when the key1 and key2 matches between two dfs?

result should look like below (I could not fit in list 6 column but expected to see it in results with same pattern as other list columns):

```
   +--+--+-----------+---------------+-----+------------+--------------+
   |k1|k2|list1      | list2         |list3|list4       |list5        |
   +--+--+-----------+---------------+-----+------------+--------------+
   |b |11|[car3,car8]|[price3,price8]|[2,8]|[False,False]|[1.000,2.000]| 
   |c |23|[car3,car7]|[price3,price7]|[4,7]|[False,False]|[2.500,1.500]| 
   +--+--+-----------+---------------+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

I am still new to using UDFs and could not find similar questions on stackoverflow, the only similar Q I found was using pandas([How to merge two list columns when merging DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213029/how-to-merge-two-list-columns-when-merging-dataframes)) which is super slow for my usecase. Any insight on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and would like to post it here to share with others who might face the same issue and for my future reference.

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
    from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
    from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
    from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
    from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
    from pyspark.sql.types import ByteType
    
    def concatTypesFunc(array1, array2): 
        final_array=array1+array2
        return final_array

    spark.udf.register("concat_types", concatTypesFunc, 
    ArrayType(BooleanType())
    spark.udf.register("concat_types", concatTypesFunc, 
    ArrayType(StringType())
    spark.udf.register("concat_types", concatTypesFunc, 
    ArrayType(DoubleType())
    spark.udf.register("concat_types", concatTypesFunc, 
    ArrayType(IntegerType())
    spark.udf.register("concat_types", concatTypesFunc, 
    ArrayType(LongType())
    spark.udf.register("concat_types", concatTypesFunc, 
    ByteType(LongType()) 

    df= spark.createDataFrame(
        [
     (  "a", 121  ,["car1"] ,["price1"] ,[1]  ,["False"] ,[0.000] ,["vfdvf"]),
    (   "b", 11   ,["car3"] ,["price3"] ,[2]  ,["False"] ,[1.000] ,[00000]),
    (   "c", 23   ,["car3"] ,["price3"] ,[4]  ,["False"] ,[2.500] ,["fdabh"]),
    (   "d", 250  ,["car6"] ,["price6"] ,[6]  ,["True"]  ,[0.450] ,[00000])
           
            ],table_schema
        )
    
    df2= spark.createDataFrame(
        [
     ("m", 121  ,["car5"] ,["price5"] ,[5]  ,["False"] ,[3.000] ,["vfdvf"]),
    (   "b", 11   ,["car8"] ,["price8"] ,[8]  ,["False"] ,[2.000] ,["mnfaf"]),
    (   "c", 23   ,["car7"] ,["price7"] ,[7]  ,["False"] ,[1.500] ,[00000]),
    (  "n", 250  ,["car9"] ,["price9"] ,[9]  ,["False"] ,[0.450] ,[00000])
    
    ],table_schema
        )
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("a")
    df2.createOrReplaceTempView("b")
    spark.sql("select a.key1, a.key2, concat_types(a.list1,b.list1)List1 ,concat_types(a.list2,b.list2)List2, \
    concat_types(a.list3,b.list3)List3 ,concat_types(a.list4,b.list4)List4,\
              concat_types(a.list5,b.list5)List5 ,\
              concat_types(a.list6,b.list6)List6 \
    from a inner join b on a.key1=b.key1 order by a.key1").show(truncate=False)
```

```
 +----+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------+----------+
|key1|key2|List1       |List2           |List3 |List4         |List5     |List6     |
+----+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------+----------+
|b   |11  |[car3, car8]|[price3, price8]|[2, 8]|[False][False]|[1.0, 2.0]|[0, mnfaf]|
|c   |23  |[car3, car7]|[price3, price7]|[4, 7]|[False][False]|[2.5, 1.5]|[fdabh, 0]|
+----+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**First, you need to  Create your Own Schema as I have done  below and then your code will work , please use my updated code**

Try this: You don't need a UDF, First Performed an inner join and later concatenated it

```
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import *
from collections import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
table_schema = StructType([StructField('key1', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('key2', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('list1', ArrayType(StringType()), False),
                     StructField('list2', ArrayType(StringType()), False),
                     StructField('list3', ArrayType(IntegerType()), False),
                     StructField('list4', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('list5', ArrayType(FloatType()), False),
                     StructField('list6', ArrayType(StringType()), False)
                     ])
df= spark.createDataFrame(
    [
 (  "a", 121  ,["car1"] ,["price1"] ,[1]  ,["False"] ,[0.000] ,["vfdvf"]),
(   "b", 11   ,["car3"] ,["price3"] ,[2]  ,["False"] ,[1.000] ,[00000]),
(   "c", 23   ,["car3"] ,["price3"] ,[4]  ,["False"] ,[2.500] ,["fdabh"]),
(   "d", 250  ,["car6"] ,["price6"] ,[6]  ,["True"]  ,[0.450] ,[00000])
       
        ],table_schema
    )

df2= spark.createDataFrame(
    [
 ("m", 121  ,["car5"] ,["price5"] ,[5]  ,["False"] ,[3.000] ,["vfdvf"]),
(   "b", 11   ,["car8"] ,["price8"] ,[8]  ,["False"] ,[2.000] ,["mnfaf"]),
(   "c", 23   ,["car7"] ,["price7"] ,[7]  ,["False"] ,[1.500] ,[00000]),
(  "n", 250  ,["car9"] ,["price9"] ,[9]  ,["False"] ,[0.450] ,[00000])

],table_schema
    )
df.createOrReplaceTempView("A")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("B")
spark.sql("select a.key1,a.key2,concat(a.list1,b.list1)List1 ,concat(a.list2,b.list2)List2, \
concat(a.list3,b.list3)List3 ,concat(a.list4,b.list4)List4,\
          concat(a.list5,b.list5)List5 ,\
          concat(a.list6,b.list6)List6 \
from A a inner join B  b on a.key1=b.key1 order by a.key1").show(truncate=False)

 +----+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------+----------+
|key1|key2|List1       |List2           |List3 |List4         |List5     |List6     |
+----+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------+----------+
|b   |11  |[car3, car8]|[price3, price8]|[2, 8]|[False][False]|[1.0, 2.0]|[0, mnfaf]|
|c   |23  |[car3, car7]|[price3, price7]|[4, 7]|[False][False]|[2.5, 1.5]|[fdabh, 0]|
+----+----+------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, I forgot to mention my real data is much more complex and each of these list columns can have different data types (string, integer,array,longtype,bytetype,doubletype and booleantype). I tried this solution and got mismatched type error (argumenet required string type but column2 is of array<int> type. Any way I can fix it?

Comment: Please post different type of list and arrays you have i will make  changes accordingly

Comment: Thanks Addy, just edited the question with the data types in each column that I expect to see in my real data.

Comment: Please see my updated code, I have created my own schema, then u will not get that error

Comment: The solution still not working, just noticed the concat in spark sql is valid for string type only and I need to use UDF to make appropriate changes, will post the solution once I make it for others reference and my future reference too.Thanks anyway for sharing your thoughts.