# Merge two lists that are in two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe like this:

```
worker_codes                  Capacity      new_codes
[24751454, 24751454]          2             [17425801, 74730846]
```

where worker_code and new_codes are two lists with ids and the capacity is the length of worker_code. What I would like to have is something like this:

```
list_of_codes                  capacity
[17425801, 74730846, 24751454] 3
```

So to merge the two lists removing duplicates and set the new capacity to the length of the new list. How can I do this?

Comment: Here for two dfs, but after the merger, the procedure is what you want: [How to merge two list columns when merging DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213029/how-to-merge-two-list-columns-when-merging-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

You can add lists together to get a joint list, and then convert to `set` (and then back to `list`) to remove duplicates:

```
df['list_of_codes']  = (df['worker_codes'] + df['new_codes']).apply(set).apply(list)
df['Capacity'] = df['list_of_codes'].apply(len)
df[['list_of_codes','Capacity']]
```

output:

```
    list_of_codes                   Capacity
0   [17425801, 24751454, 74730846]  3
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the lists are strings, how can I convert them into lists? Because otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'worker_codes':   [[24751454, 24751454]], 'Capacity': [2], 'new_codes': [[17425801, 74730846]]})
output = {'list_of_codes':[], 'capacity': []}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = row['worker_codes']
    temp.extend(row['new_codes'])
    temp = set(temp)
    output['list_of_codes'].append(temp)
    output['capacity'].append(len(temp))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

Actually, you need to merge the values of different columns then add them to a dictionary which then will be used to make a new df. The output:

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention that the lists are strings, how can I convert them into lists? Because otherwise it will fail.

Comment: Get a sample from strings format. Are they in the format s = '[123, 567]'? Then use [x.strip() for x in s[1:-1].split(',')]